# Error:Execution failed for task 'ndkBuild'. > Process 'command 'Android\sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-ndk

My project uses the Android NDK and i am getting the above error when i build.

- I installed the latest Java version, Android NDK and Android SDK
- Using Windows 8 and Android Studio
  I have added SDK and NDK in local.properties

---

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Jang\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Jang\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

---

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.digitalsquid.netspoofer"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile project(':androidsupportv4preferencefragment')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkLibsToJar, ndkBinariesToJar, ndkBinariesToJar16, ndkDataToJar
}

task ndkLibsToJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild', description: 'Create a JAR of the native libs') {
    destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
    baseName 'ndk-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from(new File(buildDir, 'libs')) {
        include '**/*.so'
    }
    into 'lib/'
}


task ndkBinariesToJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild', description: 'Create a JAR of the native binaries') {
    destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
    baseName 'ndk-binaries'
    extension 'jar'
    from(new File(buildDir, 'libs')) {
        include '**/arp-scan'
        include '**/arpspoof'
        include '**/iptables'
    }
    into 'assets/binaries/android-9'
}

task ndkBinariesToJar16(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild16', description: 'Create a JAR of the native binaries for Android 16+') {
    destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
    baseName 'ndk-binaries-16'
    extension 'jar'
    from(new File(buildDir, 'android-16/libs')) {
        include '**/arp-scan'
        include '**/arpspoof'
        include '**/iptables'
    }
    into 'assets/binaries/android-16'
}


task ndkDataToJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: 'ndkBuild', description: 'Create a JAR of the native data') {
    destinationDir new File(buildDir, 'libs')
    baseName 'ndk-data'
    extension 'jar'
    from(new File('src/main/jni/arp-scan')) {
        include '**/ieee-iab.txt'
        include '**/ieee-oui.txt'
        include '**/mac-vendor.txt'
    }
    into 'assets/data/'
}


task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
    println(ndkDir)
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk',
            '-j1'
}

task ndkBuild16(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK for Android 16+') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
    println(ndkDir)
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/android-16',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application-16.mk',
            '-j1'
}
```

---

This is build log:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:androidnetspoof:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\Jang\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
C:\Users\Jang\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
:androidnetspoof:preBuild
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:androidnetspoof:preDebugBuild
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:androidnetspoof:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preBuild
:androidnetspoof:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preReleaseBuild
:androidnetspoof:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:checkReleaseManifest
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:androidnetspoof:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidnetspoof:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:prepareReleaseDependencies
:androidnetspoof:ndkBuild
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, realpath obj, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, realpath obj, ...) failed.
Warning:warning: overriding commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
Warning:warning: ignoring old commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, realpath obj, ...) failed.
Warning:warning: overriding commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
Warning:warning: ignoring old commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, realpath obj, ...) failed.
Warning:warning: overriding commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
Warning:warning: ignoring old commands for target `/extensions/gen_initext.c'
C:\Users\Jang\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\build-binary.mk
Warning:(464) warning: overriding commands for target `build/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: overriding commands for target `build/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: overriding commands for target `build/obj/local/mips/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/obj/local/mips/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: overriding commands for target `build/obj/local/x86/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
Warning:(464) warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/obj/local/x86/objs/ext/extensions/libipt_standard.o'
[armeabi] Install        : arp-scan => libs/armeabi/arp-scan
[armeabi] Install        : arpspoof => libs/armeabi/arpspoof
mkdir -p /extensions/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make.exe: *** [/extensions/gen_initext.c] Error 1
:androidsupportv4preferencefragment:prepareReleaseDependencies FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':androidnetspoof:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jang\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Have you tried to build ndk part manually?. Also can you post your local.properties?

Comment: This is project link: https://github.com/w-shackleton/android-netspoof

Comment: `mkdir -p /extensions/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.` If this mkdir tries to create a folder in your `/` then it might not have the appropriate permissions. Maybe this application in order to work needs root access?

Comment: It's not about the permissions. He's trying to build in Windows where the directory structure uses backslash "\" not "/", also I don't think it supports the -p flag

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure too add the contents of [this](https://github.com/w-shackleton/arp-scan) repository to `jni/arp-scan/arp-scan`
- Also make sure to add the contents of [this](https://github.com/w-shackleton/custom-android-iptables) repository to `jni/iptables/custom-android-iptables`

If it doesn't work, change the flag of **ndkBuild** task `commandLine` to -j1 to make sure it does not build in parallel:

```
commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
        'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
        'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
        'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk',
        '-j1'
```

---

## **Edit after posting the build log**

This error happens because in the makefile `custom-android-iptabes/Android.mk` there is a script that executes `mkdir -p /extensions/`  and that is **UNIX** based while, I assume, you are trying to build from Windows who is **DOS** based.

What you need to do is to translate those UNIX based scripts into DOS based, for example, in this case, `mkdir \extenstions\`

Comment: I have done all thing above but that error exists. When i try build ndk part manually, i have prolem: make.exe has stopped working.

Comment: Mmm, that's weird. I already built the project successfully. Mind posting the whole build.gradle file and the whole build log?

Answer (score 0):

Setting environment variable **NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION** to **4.9** can solve the issue

[image]